# Do my outgoing gas fees of a single transaction increase if my sending wallet contains ETH made up of many small transactions?

Tags: transactions, gas, fees, mining-pools

I'm still learning about how ethereum calculates fees, and I wondered if I would have to pay more to send ethereum from my wallet if my wallet received smaller transactions as opposed to a single large transaction.

For example, if I received 100 payments of 0.01 ETH, my wallet would contain 1 ETH. If I sent that single ETH to another wallet, would my single transaction be relatively large since it would have to reference 100 previous transactions? Would the fee be significantly less if my wallet had instead received a single payment of 1 ETH, which I then used to send to another wallet?

I'm mainly asking because I realize I can define a minimum payment threshold from my mining pool. Assuming that the pool transaction fee is a standard percentage (ie there isn't a static fee), it wouldn't matter whether I was paid every day or once every few weeks, as my main wallet would end up with the same amount regardless.

However, if I then had to pay more in gas when I wanted to actually use those funds, I would be better off receiving larger chunks of ETH so that my later transactions would have fewer references, making a smaller byte-size transaction.

Is this at all accurate to how transactions work on the ethereum network? And if so, are the sizes of the transactions in those two scenarios significantly different, or miniscule enough to ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the "gas fee" is in no relation to how a given balance was accumulated.

The only factors in the **transaction fee** is the *gas amoun*t (this unit represents computational steps to pay for) and the *gas price* (the price you are willing to pay per gas).

Note that Ethereum uses an Account Model, unlike Bitcoin, which is based on UTXO (unspent transaction output).

Comment: Learn something new every day. I didn't realize ethereum wasn't based on utxo like bitcoin is (nor did I know that terminology, just the basic idea). Thanks!